# Ho can I put my custom made emoji designs into keyboard on phone?

Tags: ios, keyboard, emoji

I have created custom emoji's and need to set them us as keyboard in my iPhone.
What should I save the files as 
and 
how do I export them to a keyboard and upload it to my phone?

Answer (score 2):

To have your custom emoji's appear on your phone, you will need to create a custom font that includes them, and install that font on your phone.  But since these emoji's are not part of the Unicode standard, nobody else will ever be able to see them (unless they also install your font), and you will not find them on any normal keyboard.  To input them and see them on your own phone you would have to also create a custom keyboard which accesses the codepoints of the custom font where they are placed.

Perhaps a better approach would be to create graphics which you could place in emails or messages.